# Appropiate size of mathmatical formula in a text

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

I used this code to inset a mathematical formula in my two-columns text.

```
($Prob_{SVM}-Prob_{MLP}$)
```

[image]

Comparing to normal text, Isn't it a little big and inappropriate? How can i fix it?

Comment: I'd write`$(Prob_{\text{SVM}} - ... )$` or better, you can define a new operator `\Prob`.

Comment: I suggest you follow @Sigur's suggestion because `$Prob$` will show as the product of `$P$`, `$r$`, `$o$`, and `$b$`. You can define your own math operators with the `\DeclareMathOperator` macro, which is defined in the `amsmath` package. (Also see [this presentation](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/Mathematics.pdf).)

Comment: BTW, \text{Prob} also works, but creating a new operator improves the horizontal spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a solution and some fakes codes with similar outputs.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Prob}{Prob}
\begin{document}
% best way
$( \Prob_{\text{SVM}} - \Prob_{\text{MLP}} )$

% fake
$( \text{Prob}_{\text{SVM}} - \text{Prob}_{\text{MLP}} )$

% ugly: product of constants P r o b
$( Prob_{\text{SVM}} - Prob_{\text{MLP}} )$
\end{document}
```

[image]